# Developer How to clean up properly when a wordpress plugin uninstalls

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

So in a plugin for wordpress that I wrote. I want to improve the plugin removal
I realized that in the uninstall process I was removing the custom tables and the options where taken care off automatically, but a custom option that stored the licence key and settings was not being removed. Even worse if the licence was active I wasnt deactivating it.

So I created a static accessor to deactivate the licence  however I thought what if deactivation fails? How do I correctly report that ?
The static accessor throws a WP errow if that happens but how do I notify the user? Keep in mind this is during a plugin deactivation so I don't have general access to plugin methods just wordpress native.

Because apparently on Stack Exchange anonmyous people downrate if you dont include code here you go:

```
static function uninstall_plugin(): void
    {
        if ( ! defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
            exit;
        }
        $users = get_users();
        foreach ($users as $user){
            delete_user_meta($user->ID,'booking');
            $user->remove_role('çlient');
        }
        require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/Licence.php';
        //inside this static function is where a potential error might occur.
        Licence::__deactivate();
        require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/Database.php';
        Database::uninstall();
        //remove custom roles
        remove_role('client');
        remove_role('my-plugin-manager');
        //remove plugin option.
        delete_option("my-plugin-option");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question is using a hook:

```
 $response = $licence->deactivate();
 /**
 *  process response to a message ie check for WP_Error etc
 */
 add_action('admin_notices',function ($message){
                    ?>
                    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
                        <p>
                            <?php
                            _e( 'An error occurred during licence deactivation! ', 'vetbook' );
                            echo "- ".$message;
                            ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                });
```

So we deactivate and then use the admin_notice hook to post the result. Customise CSS to your heart's content.